# Cannot delete .jar file association in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-association

```
C:\Windows\system32>assoc .jar
File association not found for extension .jar

C:\Windows\system32>ftype jarfile
File type 'jarfile' not found or no open command associated with it.
```

When I double click on .jar file I get "Could not find the main class" error indicating that there is a wrong association. Why is that?

Comment: Is this correct "assoc .jar"?  Is there really a space between oc and .jar?

Comment: OK Sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: I managed to delete it by removing everything containing the text .jar from the registry. Now I have a different problem - the correct association set with assoc and ftype does not work. I HATE WINDOWS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Control Panel, Add Remove Programs, chances are pretty good you will see multiple versions of Java(TM). Older versions do not play well with latest update. Remove older versions and retest

EDIT - In that case i suggest downloading [JarFix](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Miscellaneous/Jarfix.shtml)

> A solution to restore the .jar file association to the Java Runtime Environment

Comment: No older versions. I do have both JRE and JDK, but this is hardly relevant...

Comment: hallelujah, jarfix did it.

Comment: If you only knew how I hate windows...

Comment: @Demiurg i have a good idea